# Bean Creation Exception when I run Liferay module

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, exception, liferay-7

I get `Bean Creation Exception`:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creati
ng bean with name 'counterHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resourc
e [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'counterData
Source' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.spring
framework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'co
unterDataSource' defined in class path resource [META-INF/counter-infrastructure
-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'counterDataSourceImpl' while set
ting bean property 'targetDataSource';
```

I am trying to run a liferay module on a tomcat server.I use `Eclipse Luna`, `tomcat server 8.0.32`, `liferay 7.0 ga3`.I searched for helpful information, didn't find any to solve the problem.Thank you!

Comment: How did you get this problem? You just barely downloaded/unpacked Liferay, ran it and got this error? Or did you deploy a plugin or bundle on it? If so, which plugin? If it is one of yours, could you share relevant parts of your code?

Comment: It is a panel app template module created with a simple windows command line with blade cli, that is all.Then I put the module into the liferay workspace from eclipse and tried to run it on my server.This is the command: blade create -t panelapp -p com.liferay.docs -c Sample my-panel-app-project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, the problem was that I didn't have Gradle IDE incorporated and also I was trying to run the module directly on my server, but firstly I had to build it with gradle.Now I am deploying my liferay modules on serves by going to the root path of the module and applying the command with blade cli: `blade deploy`.